# How to get the string before and after a line break <br>

Tags: python, html, string, beautifulsoup

The html looks like

```
<a>   
   "1447 Acres &nbsp; Council, Adams County, ID"
    <br>
    "1,190,000" 
</a>
```

How can i individually get the 1447 Acres,

"Council, Adams County, ID" and the "1,190,000"

Comment: What did you try? Are you using some html parser, or parsing yourself? Show the code you currently have.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Beautifulsoup. The website I'm trying to scrape is landwatch.com

Comment: @Nadril what do you mean to "Individually get.."? each one should be a separate variable?

Comment: Show your code, explain what does not work, provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Mendel G I would like to store the string containing the acres, location and price all in separate variables.

Comment: how about normal `split('<br>')` ?

Comment: `soup.text` gives you text with `\n` so you can try `soup.text.split('\n')`

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

html_text = '<a>   "1447 Acres &nbsp; Council, Adams County, ID" <br> 
              "1,190,000" </a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
print(soup.text)
```

Comment: This combines all the text into a single string, I want to get the location and price separately.

Comment: split the result with multiple spaces

Comment: or using re you can get fields based on " ".. try this:   text = soup.text
    contents = re.findall('"(.*?)"',text)

Comment: Thank you I'll try that

Answer (score 1):

`soup.text` gives text with original `\n` and you could use `split('\n')` to split it but there are many `\n` and it could gives empty elements.

But `BeautifulSoup` has also method `get_text()` which can get arguments `separator=` and `strip=` which can use like this

```
text = soup.get_text(separator='|', strip=True)
```

and this gives string

```
"1447 Acres   Council, Adams County, ID"|"1,190,000"
```

and now you can use `strip('|')` to split into list

```
['"1447 Acres \xa0 Council, Adams County, ID"', '"1,190,000"']
```

I would also add `replace()` to remove `"`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '''<a>     
   "1447 Acres &nbsp; Council, Adams County, ID"
    <br>
    "1,190,000" 
</a>'''

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

text = soup.get_text(separator='|', strip=True)
text = text.replace('"', '')

data = text.split('|')
print(data)
```

Result

```
['1447 Acres \xa0 Council, Adams County, ID', '1,190,000']
```

It would need also some function (probably in `urllib`) to convert entities like `&nbsp;` to correct chars or you may remove it using `replace('\xa0', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I understand that you want to  save every string to a different variable. You can try this:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<a>   
   "1447 Acres &nbsp; Council, Adams County, ID"
    <br>
    "1,190,000" 
</a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

a_tag = soup.find("a").get_text(strip=True)

a_tag = a_tag.replace(u"\xa0", "").replace('"', " ").strip()

# Split either on a double space or on a comma - which is not a digit
acres, council, location, id_, price = re.split(r"\s{2}|,[^0-9]", a_tag)

print(acres)
print(council)
print(location)
print(id_)
print(price)
```

Output:

```
1447 Acres
Council
Adams County
ID
1,190,000
```